# jquery $.ajax gives 404 not found. Im using node.js with express

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

This jquery:

```
  $.ajax({
    method: "post",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/ajax"
  });
```

is giving error 404 not found. Here is my server side:

```
router.get('/ajax', function(req, res ,ext){
    var strings = ["rad", "bla", "ska"]

    console.log('body: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));
    console.log("AJAX RECEIVED");
    res.send(strings);
});
```

so i do have the /ajax route. When i go to http://localhost:3000/ajax im able to acccess the site . However, when I try to access it with the ajax method I get the 404 error. So im wondering if the error could be with my code, or if it could be the firewall on my computer. Im actually using a company computer that has a firewall that blocks certain sites and I cannot disable it.

Comment: Solved. It was using the router.post instead of get. Thank you all.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do a HTTP POST, use `router.post`, not `router.get`.

Answer (score 0):

your `$.ajax` call is using `POST` but your route in express.js is only listening for `GET` requests.

When you hit the URL through the browser it's doing a GET, so it worked.

You would need to set up a route for POST with `router.post('/ajax', ...)`